# Мне нужна помощь с задачей по Питону

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста с задачей Москвичи
На вход программы поступает zip-архив c именем input.zip.
В этом архиве есть несколько json-документов (они могут располагаться как в корне архива, так и в произвольных каталогах), в каждом из которых хранится информация о некотором человеке. Информация содержит данные об имени, возрасте, телефоне и городе проживания человека:

```
{ 
 "age": 20, 
 "phone": "+73539215818", 
 "name": "Anna", 
 "city": "Vienna" 
}
```

Нужно вычислить и вывести на экран количество людей, проживающих в городе Москве, то есть необходимо обработать те записи, у которых параметр `city` содержит значение `Москва`.

Формат ввода
Файл input.zip

Формат вывода
Целое число, например
23

Вот мой код:

```
import json
import os
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("input.zip") as myzip:
    myzip.extractall(path=None, members=None, pwd=None)
paths = []
for currentdir, dirs, files in os.walk(os.curdir):
    for i in files:
        if currentdir != ".":
            if ".json" == i[-5:]:
                paths.append(f"{currentdir[2:]}/{i}")
        else:
            if ".json" == i[-5:]:
                paths.append(f"{i}")
# print(paths)
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.curdir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".json"):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), "rt", encoding="utf-8") as contact:
                if json.load(contact).get("city", "") == "Москва":
                    count += 1
print(count)
```

Не работает на 3-м тесте

Comment: в чём заключаетя «3-м тест»? изложите, пожалуйста, непосредственно в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: Вообще нет я не москвич. Я из глуши Саратова. И ещё, это весь код или часть которую нужно заменить?
А так за помощь спасибо.

Comment: Поставьте в тексте вопроса "Москвичи" в кавычки что ли. А то непонятно, что это название задачи, впечатление, что вы спрашиваете только москвичей вам помочь ))

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то, чтобы пройтись по нужным файлам, не обязательно распаковывать весь архив. А вдруг архив очень большой, и в текущей директории не хватит места? А вдруг для текущей директории отсутствуют права на запись? А если вдруг в архиве окажется файл с таким же именем как и ваша программа (да и с любым именем совпадающим с уже существующими файлами) - ведь распаковка затрёт всё? Да и мало ли ещё какой "а вдруг"...
К тому же, а подтирать весь этот уже не нужный распакованный мусор за собой кто будет?

```
import json
import zipfile

count = 0
with zipfile.ZipFile("input.zip") as myzip:
    for file in myzip.namelist():
        if not myzip.getinfo(file).is_dir() and file.endswith(".json"):
            with myzip.open(file) as contact:
                if json.load(contact).get("city", "") == "Москва":
                    count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: А вы москвич? а то мало ли, вопрос не вам был ;)